# Isn't this a bug?

Tags: support, migration

How is this possible to have 35 views with 59 answers. Yeah, maybe each person can answer twice. But hey, 35 views, and 35 vote ups?

[image]

This one's from larger view:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question itself explains at the bottom:

> #### migrated from stackoverflow.com 3 hours ago
>
> This question came from our site for professional and enthusiast programmers.

Comment: Well, does this mean that those 35 votes and 50 answers are from stackoverflow? If so, isn't it a design bug not to import the statistics of a question from another site?

Comment: no, because it did not get those views *on this site*

Comment: @Jeff - why is it not the same for votes and answers? Since the UI gives no indication of it being "on this site", the confusion seems understandable. As one of the most prominent UI elements, it could probably be a bit more intuitive IMHO.